# How do I get three non-colinear points on a plane? - C++

Tags: c++, math, computational-geometry, linear-algebra

I'm trying to implement at line-plane intersection algorithm. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection) I need three non-colinear points on the plane to do that.

I therefore tried implementing [this algorithm](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110208155831AAAuuwO&r=w&show_comments=true&pa=FZB6NWHjDG3N56z6v_2xXHROAYBIZOHrMtsP40rDtUdMwIdIub7uGQ--&paid=add_comment#openions) in C++, however. Something is definitely wrong, cause it makes no sense that I can choose whatever x and y coordinates and they'll fit in the plane. What if the plane is vertical and along the x-axis? No point with y=1 would then be in the plane.

I realize that this problem has been posted a lot on StackOverflow, and I see lots of solutions where the plane is defined by 3 points. But I only have a normal and a position. And I can't test my line-plane intersection algorithm before I sort out my non-colinear point finder.

The problem right now, is that I'm dividing by normal.z, and that obviously won't work when normal.z is 0.

I'm testing with this plane: Plane* p = new Plane(Color(), Vec3d(0.0,0.0,0.0), Vec3d(0.0,1.0,0.0)); // second parameter : position, third parameter : normal

The current code gives this incorrect answer:

```
{0 , 0 , 0} // alright, this is the original
{12.8377 , 17.2728 , -inf} // obviously this is not a non-colinear point on the given plane
```

Here's my code:

```
std::vector<Vec3d>* Plane::getThreeNonColinearPoints() {
    std::vector<Vec3d>* v = new std::vector<Vec3d>();

    v->push_back(Vec3d(position.x, position.y, position.z)); // original position can serve as one of the three non-colinear points.

    srandom(time(NULL));

    double rx, ry, rz, start;

    rx = Plane::fRand(10.0, 20.0);
    ry = Plane::fRand(10.0, 20.0);
    // Formula from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Definition_with_a_point_and_a_normal_vector
    // nx(x-x0) + ny(y-y0) + nz(z-z0) = 0
    // |-----------------| <- this is "start"
    //I'll try to insert position as x0,y0,z0 and normal as nx,ny,nz, and solve the equation
    start = normal.x * (rx - position.x) + normal.y * (ry - position.y);
    // nz(z-z0) = -start
    start = -start;
    // (z-z0) = start/nz
    start /= normal.z; // division by zero
    // z = start+z0
    start += position.z;
    rz = start;

    v->push_back(Vec3d(rx, ry, rz));

    // TODO one more point

    return v;
}
```

I realize that I might be trying to solve this totally wrong. If so, please link a concrete implementation of this. I'm sure it must exist, when I see so many line-plane intersection implementations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can, in fact, describe any plane with the equation `ax + by + cz == d`.  Any plane with `b == 0.0` will be parallel to the y-axis (as you describe), because in that case the value of `y` cannot affect the (in)equality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A plane can be defined with several ways. Typically a point on the plane and a normal vector is used. To get the normal vector from three points (`P1`, `P2`, `P3` ) take the cross product of the side of the triangle

```
P1 = {x1, y1, z1};
P2 = {x2, y2, z2};
P3 = {x3, y3, z3};

N = UNIT( CROSS( P2-P1, P3-P1 ) );
Plane P = { P1, N }
```

The reverse, to go from a point `P1` and normal `N` to three points, you start from any direction `G` *not* along the normal `N` such that `DOT(G,N)!=0`. The two orthogonal directions along the plane are then

```
//try G={0,0,1} or {0,1,0} or {1,0,0}
G = {0,0,1};
if( MAG(CROSS(G,N))<TINY ) { G = {0,1,0}; }
if( MAG(CROSS(G,N))<TINY ) { G = {1,0,0}; }
U = UNIT( CROSS(N, G) );  
V = CROSS(U,N);
P2 = P1 + U;
P3 = P1 + V;
```

A line is defined by a point and a direction. Typically two points (`Q1`, `Q2`) define the line

```
Q1 = {x1, y1, z1};
Q2 = {x2, y2, z2};
E = UNIT( Q2-Q1 );
Line L = { Q1, E }
```

The intersection of the line and plane are defined by the point on the line `r=Q1+t*E` that intersects the plane such that `DOT(r-P1,N)=0`. This is solved for the scalar distance `t` along the line as

```
t = DOT(P1-Q1,N)/DOT(E,N);
```

and the location as

```
r = Q1+(t*E);
```

NOTE: The `DOT()` returns the dot-product of two vector, `CROSS()` the cross-product, and `UNIT()` the unit vector (with magnitude=1).

```
DOT(P,Q) = P[0]*Q[0]+P[1]*Q[1]+P[2]*Q[2];
CROSS(P,Q) = { P[1]*Q[2]-P[2]*Q[1], P[2]*Q[0]-P[0]*Q[2], P[0]*Q[1]-P[1]*Q[0] };
UNIT(P) = {P[0]/sqrt(DOT(P,P)), P[1]/sqrt(DOT(P,P)), P[2]/sqrt(DOT(P,P))};
t*P =  { t*P[0], t*P[1], t*P[2] };
MAG(P) = sqrt(P[0]*P[0]+P[1]*P[1]+P[2]*P[2]);
```

Comment: I think this is a very down-to-earth and approachable answer. I understand that the cross product in code listing 2 effectively rotates the normal vector, yes? I was also wondering, what happens if there is no intersection in your line-plane intersection algorithm. Will the code assigning ``t`` in listing 4 produce garbage or a division by zero? Thanks.

Comment: @user309483 - The cross product finds the common normal from the two vectors. It is not necessarily a rotation. If the plane normal `N` is perpendicular to the line direction `E` then their dot product is zero and `t` goes divide by zero.

Comment: Thanks so much, I now implemented this in C++ and it works. Anyone who wants the code should message me!

Answer (score 2):

One approach you may find easy to implement is to see where the plane intersects the coordinate axes.  For the plane given by the equation`aX + bY + cZ - d = 0` hold two variables at 0 and solve for the third.  So the solutions would be (assuming `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are all non-zero):

```
(d/a, 0, 0)
(0, d/b, 0)
(0, 0, d/c)
```

You will need to consider the cases where one or more of the coefficients are 0 so you don't get a degenerate or colinear solutions.  As an example if exactly one of the coefficients is 0 (say `a=0`) you instead use

```
(1, d/b, 0)
(0, d/b, 0)
(0, 0, d/c)
```

If exactly two of the coefficients are 0 (say `a=0` and `b=0`) you can use:

```
(1, 0, d/c)
(0, 1, d/c)
(0, 0, d/c)
```

If `d=0`, the plane intersects the three axes at the origin, and so you can use:

```
(1, 0, -a/c)
(0, -c/b, 1)
(-b/a, 1, 0)
```

You will need to work out simular cases for `d` and exactly one other coefficient being 0, as well as `d` and two others being 0.  There should be a total of 16 cases, but there are a few things that come to mind which should make that somewhat more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Where `N=(Nx,Ny,Nz)` is the normal, you could project the points `N`, `(Ny,Nz,Nx)`, `(Nz,Nx,Ny)` onto the plane: they're guaranteed to be distinct.

Alternatively, if `P` and `Q` are on the plane, `P+t(Q-P)xN` is also on the plane for any `t!=0` where `x` is the cross product.

Alternatively if `M!=N` is an arbitrary vector, `K=MxN` and `L=KxN` are colinear with the plane and any point `p` on the plane can be written as `p=Origin+sK+tL` for some `s,t`.

Comment: One case where your first approach will fail is when the three components of the normal vector are all the same (e.g. N = (1, 1, 1)).

Comment: More robust method: if |Nx|>|Ny| then P = (-Nz, 0, Nx) else P = (0, -Nz, Ny)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this: "if ``M!=N`` is an arbitrary vector". By "!=" you mean "doesn't equal", right? How can the result of a boolean expression be a vector? Thanks for your patience. I understand "K=MxN are colinear" because they equal each other and therefore you mean that they are both colinear". But how should I interpret this when it's "not equals"?

Comment: Interpret it as "where M is an arbitrary vector such that M!=N"