# Imaginary triangle Area

Tags: 3d, geometry, area

I am trying to calculate the area of a triangle in 3D space, and I am using Heron's formula.

I am getting an imaginary result, with 0 for the real part.

Do you know what this means?

I am trying to determine if the points of the triangle are colinear (area of triangle 0)

Thank you

Comment: Please show us what you have (`code`)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8387199/380384

Answer (score 2):

Heron's formula fails if the three sides don't form a triangle (triangle inequality is not satisfied).

Note that, when using floating point numbers, you cannot test for zero, because a floating point number is almost never zero due to rounding errors.

An alternative way to check for collinearity:

To determine if A,B,C are collinear, calculate the cross-product (A-B)x(A-C). If its length is less than a fixed epsilon, then the points are collinear within some tolerance. If your input is given as integers, you can test for an exact zero.

If the cross-product returns a non-zero result, then its length is twice the triangle area.

Answer (score 1):

Heron's formula is actually unstable for triangles with very small angles 
[This link has the stable alternative to the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctI4L.png)
where a ≥ b ≥ c

Answer (score 0):

It means you have made an error in your calculation.  Any three non-collinear points in 3D space form a triangle.  The lengths of that triangle's sides, when plugged into Heron's formula, will yield a real area greater than 0.  Mathematically, no other result is possible.  And if the three points are collinear then the area will be 0.

From a debugging perspective, I'd say you should examine the three lengths you are plugging into Heron's formula.  If they fail the Triangle Inequality, then you have miscalculated them.  If they pass, then you are not applying Heron's formula correctly.