# how to calculate four arbitrary points from a plane equation

Tags: geometry, plane

I have a normal vector, the equation of a plane (ax+by+cz=d)

How could I calculate four arbitrary points to create a quadrilateral? I thought about just using the x,y, and z intercepts but that approach will not work.

I am thinking I will have to use a system of equations in numpy http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

this post outline an approach in c++ but I am not sure if it would work
[How do I get three non-colinear points on a plane? - C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387199/how-do-i-get-three-non-colinear-points-on-a-plane-c?rq=1)

Comment: It _will_ work: 3 non-colinear points will form a complete 2D basis in the plane, and any point on the plane is representable as a linear combination of the two basis vectors

Comment: ill implement it in python, any idea how I could get that fourth point. i would prefer to avoid using the x,y,z plane intercepts

Comment: as I said you can get _any_ point on the plane using a linear combination of the two vectors you obtain from the 3-point method you were wondering about

Comment: Having `A,B,C` non-collinear points in the plane, make the fourth point `D = B + (C-A)`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

1. Solve the homogeneous system `ax + by + cz = 0`. The solution will give your two linearly independent solutions `A = (x0, y0, z0)` and `B = (x1, y1, z1)`.
2. Find a particular solution (assuming here that `d != 0`). To do this select a coefficient `a`, `b` or `c` which is different from `0`. For instance, if `a != 0` a particular solution is `P = (d/a, 0, 0)`.
3. Select 4 points in the homogeneous plane, e.g., `0`, `A`, `B` and `A + B`, and sum to them the particular solution `P`

   A + P, B + P, A + B + P, P

Comment: that was not me, i just saw your post. thank you for the response. I am also considering replicating the sympy arbitrary point method. http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/plane.html

Comment: Thanks @webmaker. Just let me know if there is something I should clarify better.